# How can I set the inner JSONArray into a ListView?

Tags: android, json

I'm working with a JSON like this and I have to set into a ListView the `"name", "books"` and the `"price"` of each book. I've set just `"name"` and `"books"` in my List but **I don't know how can I set the inner** `JSONArray "price"` in each item of my ListView that corresponding to each name (does this make sense?).

So, How can i do that? any ideas?. Thanks for your time and your answers :)

```
{ "users”: 
    [ {     “name” : “Jaime”,
            “books” : "3”,
            “price” : 
                [   
                    {"1”: “90.00" },
                    {"2”: ”90.00" }, 
                    {"3”: "95.00”} 
                ],
        },

        {   “name” : “Carl”,
            “books":"5”,
            “price”:
                [ 
                    {"1”: "88.00”},
                    {"2”: "100.00”},
                    {"3”: "100.00”},
                    {"4”: "100.00”},
                    {"5”: "100.00”}
                ]
        }
    }
```

A little example of what I want to do, is:

```
  ----------------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------------

       |      Jaime        books: 3        |
       |        90  -  90  - 95            |

       |      Carls        books: 5        |
       |    88 - 100 - 100 - 100 - 100     |




    -------------------------------------------
```

My code is:

```
try {
            JSONArray users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> names = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++){
                HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();

                JSONObject infoUsers= users.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray price = infoUsers.optJSONArray("price");

                String name = infoUsers.getString("name");
                String books = infoUsers.getString("books");

                info.put("name", name);
                info.put("books", books);

                for(int g = 0; g < price.length(); g++){
                    Log.d("Price ", g + " " + price.optString(g));

                }

                names.add(info);
            }

            String[] keys = {KEY_NAME,KEY_MATERIA};

            int[] ids = {R.id.name, R.id.books};

            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    names, R.layout.name_and_books, keys, ids);
            myList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Application ", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```

and my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/books"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="Books" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The simple way to do this is  Gson parse

Comment: try making two separate Bean/Model Class with getter/setter methods in which one class contains the book detail with ArrayList<PriceDetails> and one class contains price details